# Show SBT's internal classpath

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to `show` or `export` SBT's own set of internal dependencies?

For example, if I run `sbt "show fullClasspath"` it does not include `org.scala-lang.scala-compiler`. And if my application's version of Scala is different from SBT's version (such as a Play app using 2.11 and SBT 0.13.5) then there are tons of unlisted jars SBT needs when running `sbt compile`.

The motivation for this is that I'm attempting to prune my `.ivy2/cache` to reduce the size of a disk image containing my app code (without re-downloading anything upon `sbt compile`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `reload plugins`, which changes the current build to the `project/`:

> The reload plugins command changes the current build to the (root)
>   project’s project/ build definition. This allows manipulating the
>   build definition project like a normal project. reload return changes
>   back to the original build. Any session settings for the plugin
>   definition project that have not been saved are dropped.

When selected the build definition, you can do `show fullClasspath`.

If you want to do this without launching sbt console first, you can do `sbt "reload plugins" "show fullClasspath"`.

Comment: This is really close to what I need, but it's not showing what I expect. If I run this on a Play 2.3.x with `scalaVersion := "2.11.1"` set, it does not list `scala-compiler 2.11`, but instead lists `scala-compiler 2.10`. I suspect this is because from the `project/` it doesn't consider my `build.sbt`.

Comment: @joekutner sorry I misunderstood your question. These dependencies are actually sbt's dependencies (for sbt it doesn't matter what you select it will always use its own Scala version). Normally the `show fullClasspath` shows the dependencies for your project. The compiler will not be included because technically it's not a dependency. See first sentence here http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Classpaths.html#basics

Comment: This is still very useful, so i will mark the question as answered. But it probably won't be my ultimate solution because I can't afford to have sbt resolve all artifacts every time I reload. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Wasn't there just a long thread about controlling sbt's own dependencies, because of the problem downloading 2.10.2? This PR: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1494  Maybe that helps somehow.